# Convert from underscore.js to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I came across this piece of code in Underscore.js, I want to convert this to vanilla javascript.  Any idea on how to do that ?

```js
var makeLetters = function(word) { 
    return _.map(word.split(''), function(character) {
        return { name: character, chosen: false };
    });
}
```

This is the current output from the above function, I want to retain the same structure, except I want to accomplish this in regular javascript.

```
0: {name: "s", chosen: false, $$hashKey: "003"}
1: {name: "c", chosen: false, $$hashKey: "004"}
2: {name: "o", chosen: false, $$hashKey: "005"}
3: {name: "p", chosen: false, $$hashKey: "006"}
4: {name: "e", chosen: false, $$hashKey: "007"}
```

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: You couldn't find [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in a quick search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
// Your current Underscore code:
/*
var makeLetters = function(word) { 
  return _.map(word.split(''), function(character) {
  return { name: character, chosen: false };
});
*/

// New ES6+ code:
const makeLetters = (word) => word.split('').map(character => ({ name: character, chosen: false }));

// If you aren't using ES6+:
var makeLetters = function(word) {
  return word.split('')
    .map(function(character) {
      return { name: character, chosen: false };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var makeLetterWord="scope";
        var makeLettersSplit = makeLetterWord.split('').map(function(character) {
              return { name: character, chosen: false };
            });
           
console.log(makeLettersSplit );
```

Comment: If you find it as useful.Please accept this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

In ES 2015+

```
function makeLetters(word) {
    return word.split('').map(v => { name: v, chosen: false });
}
```

In pre ES 5

```
function makeLetters(word) {
    return word.split('').map(function(v) {
        return { name: v, chosen: false };
    });
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, you are missing the `(` and `)` around the `{ name: v, chosen: false}` object, which is required to let the compiler know that you are meaning to return an object and not just function brackets. :)